# Question on Dual space $V^*$ : is there a geometrical representation?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ a $K-$vector space. I know that the dual space is $V^*=\text{Hom}(V,K)$. Excepted that with the fact that with a basis of $V$ I can get a basis of $V^*$, is there a geometrical visualisation (or justification) of the fact that $V^*$ is the dual space ? I mean, is there a stronger connexion between $V$ and $V^*$ excepted the basis ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following result can help you:

> **Theorem:** 
>   1. The kernel of a non-zero linear form is a hyperplane. 
>   2. Every hyperplane is the kernel of a non-zero linear form. 
>   3. Two non-zero linear forms define the same hyperplane if and only if they are proportional.

For the proof: the first point follows by rank-nullity theorem, the second follows by constructing the projection on a supplementary ($\simeq \Bbb R$) of $H$.

Comment: A bit sloppy: $0$ is a functional as well.

Comment: You're right! Thanks.